# Upgrade PHP 7.0.0 RC1 to PHP 7.0 current stable version on centOS?

Tags: centos, php-7

How to remove (upgrade) the PHP 7 RC to the new stable version on centOS?

Thanks

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know where you got it from. CentOS does not have a PHP7 package in the official repository.

Comment: Hi, i get the PHP 7.0.0RC1 from the php official site. Thanks

Comment: How? Did you build and install it yourself? In that case, there may be a `make uninstall` option. If not, you need to go and manually remove the files.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip! I'll try

Comment: I install it using ./buildconf --force

Comment: I already solve the problem and i post right now the explaination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uninstall PHP 7.0 RC and install the final version of PHP 7 Realeased on 3 December, first of all you need to delete manually the directory and the files of PHP 7 RC, for that you need to do:

**1 Step:** 
Uninstall manually the PHP-7.0.0RC1 folder

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -rf php-7.0.0RC1
```

**2 Step:**
Uninstall the libphp7.so

```
cd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/
sudo rm -rf libphp7.so
```

**3 Step:**
Download the PHP 7.0.0 Realased 3 December from php.net oficial page

```
sudo wget http://php.net/get/php-7.0.0.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
```

**4 Step:**
Extract the files of *tar.bz2 from /opt

```
tar xzf php-7.0.0RC1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

**5 Step:**
Once done, let’s move into /opt/php-7.0.0 and execute the buildconf script with the –force switch in order to force the build of this new version.

```
cd /opt/php-7.0.0
ls
./buildconf --force
```

**6 Step:**
Now it’s time to execute the configure command. While the options below will ensure a standard PHP 7 installation, you can refer to the complete option list in the PHP manual in order to better customize the installation as per your needs:

```
    ./configure \
--prefix=$HOME/php7/usr \
--with-config-file-path=$HOME/php7/usr/etc \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-zip \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-exif \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-iconv \
--with-gmp \
--with-pspell \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
--with-gettext=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--with-recode=/usr \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
--with-apxs2
```

**7 Step:**
Once done, execute this command:

```
make
```

and after that:

```
make install
```

**8 Step:**
Finaly restart your apache server

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

**9 Step:** 
And it's done! Now you can run ***phpinfo()*** to check the version "PHP 7.0.0" installed.